# Right software to recreate the following illustration

Tags: software-recommendation

[image]

I'm looking for a combination of software used to model the illustration. I want to add few things shown here to my art like ancient boats, people farming, monuments. I need help to recreate this art with precision. thanks.

Comment: You could use all sorts of software for this. What matters more is your illustration skills and what software you feel most comfortable doing illustration in.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a basic pencil artwork modified in a software like Adobe Photoshop.

There's lot of tools and different brushes you can acquire and use in Adobe Photoshop to get similar pencil effects, and draw from scratch what you want. You can also use Gimp (it's free.)

It won't be easy because doing digital design demands almost as much skills and practice than doing a nice colored pencil artwork. The final result will depend on your patience and skills.

If you look for a map creation software with boats, mountains and stuff already designed for you, search for software similar to "[Campaign Cartographer 3](https://secure.profantasy.com/evidence/gallery.asp)". This one might not be maintained anymore but maybe you can find something similar online by using these keywords. That kind of software might save you time but you'll also be limited by their image bank.

It's also possible you'll need to combine more than one software to achieve this result. For example, you could create the basic maps in a software similar to the CC3 mentioned above or Adobe Illustrator, and import your design into Photoshop (or any similar software) to add some pencil filter effect. If you already feel comfortable in using a design software (any), that be be a good option for you.

Examples of filters:

http://akvis.com/en/sketch/index.php